# WordPress check if value equals and echo "checked"

Tags: metabox

Having some trouble with checking a query against another and outputting a value of checked if it matches. Have tried placing the get_post_meta in a foreach loop and it didn't work, It needs to pull in multiple "checked" boxes. Currently it's only checking one checkbox rather than multiple. The data is inside the database and the query pulls in the values in an array. I need a way to check if the meta_value of $locat matches the value of $area->id if it does echo checked in the checkbox.

Code in its current state:

```
<?php
$locat = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM location_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'locationAssigned' AND post_id = ". $post->ID);

                            $areas = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM location_locations ORDER BY locationName ASC");

                            if( count($areas) ) :
                                ?>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach($areas as $area) :
                                        ?>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="locationAssigned" name="locationAssigned[]" value="<?php echo $area->id; ?>"
                                        <?php

                                        //Check if $locat->meta_value matches $area->id echo out checked else nothing             

                                            if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'locationAssigned', true) == $area->id) { ?> 
                                            checked="checked" 
                                            <? } ?> 


                                            />&nbsp;<?php echo $area->locationName; ?><br>  

                                        <?php
                                    endforeach;
                                    ?>
                                <?php
                            endif;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of the locationAssigned post meta? Can you var dump or print_r it into a <pre> tag?

Comment: LocationAssigned outputs 16,4

Comment: Is that an array containing the values 16 and 4, or a string "16,4" ?

Comment: a:2:{i:0;s:2:"16";i:1;s:1:"4";} is whats stored inside the database